# How to test an optical sensor board from printer

Tags: sensor, optical

I have salvaged an optical sensor board from a HP printer just as the one shown [c9101-80190-A](https://i.ebayimg.com/thumbs/images/g/~owAAOSwuLZY2MC7/s-l225.jpg) to use it other hobby projects.

The problem is, I cannot be sure whether it's working or not, as I get always the same voltages (with and without séparation between the diode and the receiver) as shown in the following schematic.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLBosI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

How can I find out if a photogate is working or not?

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't really tell what I'm looking at, since this has to be a candidate for the grainiest photo ever. Maybe you could use the website-integrated schematic editor (schematic button in the question editor)?

Comment: How do you know 'D2' is a photo-diode? Did you find a datasheet for the sensor? If it is a photo-diode you have it upside down. It will conduct all the time.

Comment: To be honest, I don't know.I just used the presentation I found somewhere. I am sure there are four nodes (5V, 4.24V, 4.24V, 0V). And these are always having these values with and without obstruction

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fveTRH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A much more likely arrangement.*

Usually these are wired as shown in Figure 1.

- The LED is permanently on.
- The photo-transistor is wired in "common-emitter" mode.
- The collector has a pull-up resistor. This may be on the board you linked or it may be on another board connected to NODE2.
- With no obstruction the LED turns on Q1 and the voltage at NODE2 is pulled down close to 0 V.
- With an obstruction Q1 turns off and R2 pulls the voltage up to V+.

Comment: so I think the LED is dead

Comment: According to your diagrams you have wired it incorrectly. The LED will be infra-red. Wire it up as I have shown and see if your smartphone's camera can see it. (The sensors pick up IR.)

Comment: There isn't much to wire, as the circuit is already soldered. I just connected the ground and red to 5V. I use the green to measure the voltage

Comment: Post a decent close-up photo of the front and back of the PCB. Crop them properly.

Comment: I just posted a front picture. I can't get a descent one from the back. If necessary, I can try with another smartphone tomorrow

Comment: Yes, it's necessary.

Comment: I found [photos of the underside](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=c9101-80190-A&rlz=1C1GGRV_enIE751IE751&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi8vZ-K46LVAhXC2D4KHSPEA9AQ_AUIDCgD&biw=1538&bih=810#imgrc=I5SJYP1u64W9HM:). Your tracing seems to be on the right track. It's a weird circuit.

Comment: Yes. I was hoping if I can simulate the circuit to understand but as I have just started, I have no idea how to simulate the obstruction

Comment: Is there a part number on the slot sensor?

Comment: Ni. I can't find any